NIFI - How I can use a InvokeHttp without body in Nifi?
How I can use a InvokeHttp without body in Nifi?
I need to use a POST method with a query, example:
www.teste.com&query=
Send without a body, only in URL.

Did you try setting Request Body Enabled to false?
